# PHP Button click not reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have button.php and this code is there in button.php

```
<a href="Cancel.php<button type="button">Cancel</button></a>
```

I have Cancel.php

```
<?php 
//Do something
header("location:button.php")
?>
```

When I click the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button it should process something and return to the same PHP file.
It's returning but not reloading or updating the page content.
Is there any method to reload or my method of coding is wrong? Can I use jQuery here? Please help me!

Comment: That can't really be your code. Please post your actual code.

Comment: remove `<?php` and `?` and try `<a href="Cancel.php>Cancel</a>`. Also start learning php.

Comment: so little code, so many errors :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `header("Refresh:0");`

```
<?php 
//Do something
header("Refresh:0");
?>
```

use this for different page

```
header("Refresh:0; url=button.php");
```

Comment: No i want to back to button.php and reload! when button is clicked!

Comment: or just use `<a href="button.php>Cancel</a>`

Comment: Yha It's working! Good Help! I ve been searchng it for a long time.

Comment: @Learn M_P_C nice make sure to check it as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

You have to add simple `a` hyper link like below:

```
<?php 
<a href="Cancel.php">Cancel</a>
?>
```

Not need to `button` in hyper link you can do it another way with the button like the below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='Cancel.php';">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: You need to add `echo` to render `hyperlink` because it is in php tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JS`.

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.location.reload();return false;">Cancel</a>
```

And in PHP

```
<a href="Cancel.php>Cancel</a>
```